# Why passing an object derived from std::function by reference crashes the program?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

If I pass an object that's derived from std::function to another function by reference, the program always crashes during runtime with a bad_function_call error. As the following code shows:

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>

class foo :public std::function<int(void)> {
    public:
        int operator()(){return 1;}
};

void bar(const std::function<int(void)>& f) {std::cout << f() << std::endl;}

int main(){
    foo f;
    bar(f);
}
```

However if the functional object is passed *by value* like this:

```
void bar(std::function<int(void)> f)
```

the program runs ok. I've tested the program on gcc, clang and visual studio and the results are the same. What is causing this bad_function_call?

Comment: Why are you deriving from `std::function`.  AFAIK the function call operator is not virtual.

Comment: I know deriving from `std::function` is not a good practice. I just want to know WHY the program behaves this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::function::operator()` is not virtual.

```
class foo :public std::function<int(void)> {
  public:
    int operator()(){return 1;}
};
```

when viewing a `foo` as a `std::function`, the `operator()` you wrote does **nothing**.  You have an empty `std::function<int()>`, not one that returns 1.

`std::function` does type-erasure based polymorphism, not inheritance based polymorphism.  It can **store** anything it can invoke, copy and destroy.  You can pass it around *by value*, and the stored callable will be brought around with it.

Inheriting from it is usually not what you want to do.

```
class foo {
  public:
    int operator()(){return 1;}
};
```

This can be converted into a `std::function`.  In fact, with this change your code compiles and works.

Without this change, it prefers to cast-to-base and pass a reference to the (empty) base `std::function` to the argument.  Without inheritance, it instead attempts to convert the `foo` to a `std::function` and succeeds.

Of course, this `foo` is pretty silly.

Instead of this:

```
int main(){
  foo f;
  bar(f);
}
```

we can do this:

```
int main(){
  auto f = []{ return 1; };
  bar(f);
}
```

and it works just as well.  (The lambda above auto-generates a class that is almost identical to the `foo` type above in the important ways.  It doesn't inherit from `std::function` either.)

C++ supports more than one kind of polymorphism.  Inheritance based polymorphism doesn't (easily) permit value-types, and C++ thrives on value-types, so `std::function` was written to work with value-types.

---

As @T.C. noted below,

```
void bar(std::function<int(void)> f)
```

this works because the compiler is choosing between "slicing" to the base class and using a converting constructor, and the converting constructor is preferred by the C++ standard.

```
void bar(std::function<int(void)> const& f)
```

here it isn't preferred, because no conversion need be done, just "treat as base", and that is higher priority than constructing a new object in the rules.

In the case where we pass a lambda or an "unparented" foo, the "take a reference to parent" case isn't available, so a temporary `std::function` is created from our `foo` (or lambda) and `f` binds to it.

Comment: I agree with your analysis but how do you know categorically that std:: function is not implemented using inheritance? Isn't this implementation defined, or is there a reason why an inheritance based solution could not conform?

Comment: The initialization silliness here is also "fun". The `const &` binds directly to the base class subobject; the by-value version would have called the copy ctor to slice but was hijacked by the converting constructor.

Comment: @NirFriedman It could use inheritance as in internal detail; it could use per-compiler non-standard placement replacement of a derived class in a parent class memory.  It could use unicorns.  The standard only specifies behavior.  All I am saying is that you cannot implement `std::function` using inheritance based polymorphism (other than as an internal detail in the pimpl-equivalent) in standard C++: you can implement it using various type-erasure strategies (including using inheritance for type erasure in the pimpl).  It behaves like type-erased value-based polymorphism user code.

Answer (score 4):

Your overload is not used, the const one (`from std::function`) is used with `const std::function<int(void)>& f`.
and as you don't initialize `std::function`, it is empty and then throws when `operator ()` is called.

When you pass by value, a `std::function` is created from your functor (as any regular functor), and then `std::function` invoke your stored functor.

But don't derive from `std::function`, just use

```
auto f = [](){ return 1; };
bar(f);
```

Comment: But when passing by value, `foo` gets slices, doesn't it? It's actually *type-casted* to `std::function` (better match is irrelevant).

Comment: @IgorR.: It is subtle, `std::function<int(void)>(f)` is called, (not the copy constructor with slicing), but the one which take the functor `f`. But indeed, my explanation is inexact.

Comment: @IgorR.: No, slicing is a concept that only applies to derived classes, so _that's_ clearly not occurring. It uses the `std::function` conversion constructor, which effectively takes a reference to your lambda internally.

Comment: @Jarod42 right, the word "slicing" was incorrect here.

Answer (score 1):

```
bar(f);
```

You are passing `f` of type `foo` to `bar`, but parameter of `bar` is `const std::function<int(void)>`

Here `foo` is upcasted to const `std::function<int(void)>`.

You haven't overloaded operator() in `const std::function<int(void)>`.

So it is throwing runtime error.